# Запрос в MySQL и выбор из нескольких таблиц

Tags: php, mysql

Есть несколько одинаковых таблиц в базе. Как сделать запрос из всех? Вот запрос на выбор из одной:

```
mysql_query("select * from `table` where `dt` = '20161201'");
```

Comment: использовать UNION или UNION ALL видимо

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Спасибо.Вариант.

Answer (score 2):

`UNION` - применяется для объединения результатов двух или более SQL-запросов в единую таблицу, состоящую из схожих строк. Оба запроса должны возвращать одинаковое число столбцов и совместимые типы данных в соответствующих столбцах.

Пример

```
<запрос1>
UNION [ALL]
<запрос2>
UNION [ALL]
<запрос3>
 .....;
```

Более подробный пример

```
SELECT City, Country FROM Customers
WHERE Country='Germany'
UNION ALL
SELECT City, Country FROM Suppliers
WHERE Country='Germany'
ORDER BY City;
```

Можно писать `UNION` или `UNION ALL`.

Разница между операторами `UNION` и `UNION ALL` заключается в том, что первый выкидывает из окончательного результата повторяющиеся строки.

---

Дополнение от @teran из комментария:  в отдельный столбец можно выбрать, например, имя таблицы из которой пришли данные. а-ля

```
...., 'customers' as tbl FROM Customers
```

если вдруг необходимо будет знать, откуда реально пришли строки (что будет иметь смысл в только случае `UNION ALL`)

Comment: "двух или более" лучше поправить. Еще как вариант, в отдельный столбец можно выбрать, например, имя таблицы из которой пришли данные. а-ля `...., 'customers' as tbl FROM Customers`, если вдруг необходимо будет знать, откуда реально пришли строки (что будет иметь смысл в только случае `union all`)

Answer (score 0):

Создайте надтаблицу с использованием ENGINE=Merge. В крайнем случае объединяющий VIEW. Совсем в крайнем - UNION ALL непосредственно в запросе.

Если будете использовать просто UNION (или его синоним UNION DISTINCT) во VIEW или непосредственном запросе - приготовьтесь к могучему оверхеду на сортировку и удаление дубликатов (ну то есть тормозить будет нещадно).

Comment: Merge это для myISAM ......а если InnoDB? Если запросы c `*` то в любом случае оверхэд)

Comment: Если InnoDB, то кому-то не повезло. А вот откуда оверхед при UNION ALL, если не указаны конкретные поля и не добавлять поле идентификатора конкретной таблицы, я что-то не понял.